# Python/BeautifulSoup scraping and printing to csv

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I am writing a code to scrape electoral data and organize into a dataset.
Here's what I did:

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response= requests.get('https://elections2018.wallonie.be/fr/resultats-chiffres?el=PR&id=PRA52011')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html.parser")
soup.findAll('tr')

import pandas as pd
```

I got something like this:

```
    [<tr>
 <td>
 <p><img alt="carte de navigation" border="0" id="navmap" name="navmap" src="/sites/default/files/images/election_nav_pro_wl.gif" title="carte de navigation" usemap="#navmap"/></p>
 </td>
 </tr>,
 <tr><th class="text-left w-5"></th><th "="" class="text-left">Liste</th><th></th><th class="text-right w-10">2018</th><th class="text-right w-10">2012</th><th class="text-right w-10">%2018</th><th class="text-right w-10">%2012</th><th class="text-right w-10">+/- %</th><th class="text-right w-10">Sièges</th></tr>,
 <tr class="row-odd"><td>1</td><td>MR</td><td class="text-center"></td><td class="text-right">31.099</td><td class="text-right">40.790</td><td class="text-right">15,58%</td><td class="text-right">18,64%</td><td class="text-right">-3,07%</td><td class="c-accent02 text-right">4 (0)</td></tr>,
 <tr class="row-even"><td>2</td><td>ECOLO</td><td class="text-center"></td><td class="text-right">23.053</td><td class="text-right">22.412</td><td class="text-right">11,55%</td><td class="text-right">10,24%</td><td class="text-right">+1,30%</td><td class="c-accent02 text-right">3 (+1)</td></tr>,
 <tr class="row-odd"><td>3</td><td>PS</td><td class="text-center"></td><td class="text-right">66.358</td><td class="text-right">89.651</td><td class="text-right">33,24%</td><td class="text-right">40,98%</td><td class="text-right">-7,74%</td><td class="c-accent02 text-right">9 (-1)</td></tr>,
```

I need a csv file with the Political List/Party, Arrondissment/Circoscription and Percentage of votes per year.

How do I scrape the data needed and put them into a readable csv file?

Comment: Please can you [edit] your question to show what your desired output CSV would look like for that HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's `csv` library to create your CSV file. After getting the list of `tr` elements, you can use each one to get the list of `td` elements inside it. [`itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html?highlight=itemgetter#operator.itemgetter) can be used to then extract just the elements you want from the resulting list. For example:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

req_values = itemgetter(1, 3, 4, 5, 6)  # extract these columns from the table
response = requests.get('https://elections2018.wallonie.be/fr/resultats-chiffres?el=PR&id=PRA52011')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html.parser")
header_values = [v.text for v in soup.thead.find_all('th')]

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(req_values(header_values))
    
    for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[2:]:
        values = [v.text for v in tr.find_all('td')]
    
        if len(values) == 0:
            break
        
        csv_output.writerow(req_values(values))
```

Would give you an `output.csv` file containing:

```
Liste,2018,2012,%2018,%2012
MR,31.099,40.790,"15,58%","18,64%"
ECOLO,23.053,22.412,"11,55%","10,24%"
PS,66.358,89.651,"33,24%","40,98%"
PTB,30.384,-,"15,22%",-
PTB+,-,6.094,-,"2,79%"
CDH,12.938,25.797,"6,48%","11,79%"
PP,8.212,-,"4,11%",-
DéFI,11.640,-,"5,83%",-
Oxygène,1.655,-,"0,83%",-
AGIR,4.434,-,"2,22%",-
CA,442,-,"0,22%",-
LA DROITE,5.478,-,"2,74%",-
WALLON,1.632,-,"0,82%",-
NWA-NATION,1.412,-,"0,71%",-
PSLHDD,896,-,"0,45%",-
FDF,-,4.665,-,"2,13%"
R.W.F.,-,2.782,-,"1,27%"
DN,-,631,-,"0,29%"
FdG,-,986,-,"0,45%"
NATION,-,1.415,-,"0,65%"
NWA,-,645,-,"0,29%"
FRONT-GAUCHE,-,1.128,-,"0,52%"
R.W.,-,2.224,-,"1,02%"
FN-belge,-,12.699,-,"5,80%"
FNW,-,6.860,-,"3,14%"
```

If some page are missing results, you could try the following approach:

```
    try:
        row = req_values(values)
        csv_output.writerow(row)
    except IndexError:
        print(f"Only {len(values)} values: {values}")
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried but at the end (csv_output.writerow(req_values(values))
 I got an error: list index out of range

Comment: It probably means the table has rows with items missing, if you add a `print(values)` line before it, it would show you what the problem is. You could skip such rows. I assume you are trying it with a different URL?